# Scala Convert List[ (a, b) ] to List [ Option(a, b)]

Tags: scala

How to convert a list of tuples into List of optioned Tuple.

```
val input:List[(a,b)]=List( ("a","100"),("b","200") )

val output:List[Option(a,b)]
```

input.flatmap(Some(_)).toList does not work

Comment: Try this solution `input.map(v => Option(v))`

Comment: You want `.map`, not `.flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Vladislav Kievski and Dima.
Solution :

> input.map(Option(_))